# Text message of Word macro needs to be in the comment tab

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using Word macro, getting text message for corresponding word file in the Word file. But I need the text message in the comment tab (right end side part).

```
Dim MsgText As String
MsgText = "some text message"
Selection.TypeText Text:=MsgText
```

I need the text message to be on the comment panel tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
With Selection
  .Comments.Add Range:=.Range, Text:=MsgText
End With
```